# how to upgrade laravel version from 5.0.33 to 6.x

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have changed `php` version to `7.1.3` and also `Laravel` version in `composer.json` file. Then simply use composer update but nothing happens. I need help.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.1 will no longer be actively maintained as of December 2019. Therefore, Laravel 6.0 requires PHP 7.2 or greater.just follow the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade